# weka inital heap size memory allocated

Tags: heap-memory, weka, rweka

i am currently using WEKA and i am trying to run a logistic regression on a dataset that i am currently working, on however everytime i attempt to do this WEKA shuts down and shows me this message i am unsure how to remedy this issue.
[image: out of memory error message screenshot]

I tried using chatgpt to answers by adding a -xmx with the target shortcut but this did not change the outcome. i have been told previously that i could use IDE but i am not able to for this work i am completing so any advice on what i can do instead of that would be most appreciated Iam currently using a windows computer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried setting the `-Xmx ..` option through the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable (as described in the [Weka wiki](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/OutOfMemoryException/))?